# Python - name 'height' is not defined

Tags: python, global-variables, turtle-graphics

I have a computer science assignment where I need to write a function `main()` that calls a function `drawChessboard()` to draw an 8x8 chessboard where the user can determine the width and height of the board. We are learning about functions and modules and we need to use more than one module with multiple functions. Here is the first module I have:

```
from chessboard import *

def main():

    startX, startY = eval(input("Enter the starting coordinates (x, y): "))
    width = input("Enter the width: ")
    height = input("Enter the height: ")
    spaceX = eval(width) / 8
    spaceY = eval(height) / 8

    def variables():
        global startX, startY, width, height, spaceX, spaceY, xLocation, yLocation

    if width == "" and height == "":
        drawChessboard(startX, startY)
    elif height == "":
        drawChessboard(startX, startY, width=eval(width))
    elif width == "":
        drawChessboard(startX, startY, height=eval(height))
    else:
        drawChessboard(startX, startY, eval(width), eval(height))


main()
```

Here is the second module called: chessboard.py

```
import turtle

global startX, startY, width, height, spaceX, spaceY, xLocation, yLocation

def drawRectangle():  # Define draw rectangle function

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(xLocation, yLocation)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.forward(spaceX)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(spaceY)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(spaceX)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(spaceY)
    turtle.end_fill()


def drawAllRectangles(startX, startY):          # function that will draw all rectangles to make up chessboard

    yLocation = startY
    while yLocation <= (height - 2 * spaceY):   # draw rectangles on rows 1, 3, 5, 7
        global xLocation
        xLocation = startX
        while xLocation <= (width - 2 * spaceX):
            drawRectangle()
            xLocation += 2 * spaceX
        yLocation += 2 * spaceY

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(startX + spaceX, startY + spaceY)
    turtle.pendown()
    yLocation = startY + spaceY
    while yLocation <= (height - spaceY):       # draw rectangles on rows 2, 4, 6, 8
        xLocation = startX + spaceX
        while xLocation <= (width - spaceX):
            drawRectangle()
            xLocation += 2 * spaceX
        yLocation += 2 * spaceY

def drawChessboard(startX, startY, width = 250, height = 250):

    import turtle

    turtle.showturtle()         # Draw outside border for chessboard
    turtle.speed(10)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(startX, startY)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.forward(width)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(height)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(width)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(height)

    drawAllRectangles(startX, startY)

    turtle.done()
```

When I try to run the first module, it gives me an error from the first `while` statement of `drawAllRectangles()` that says 
name `height` is not defined.
I don't know how to fix this. I tried making all of the variables global but it still gives me the same result. I looked up the error on this website, but I've had no luck. Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You used height twice in this function

```
def drawAllRectangles(startX, startY):          # function that will draw all rectangles to make up chessboard

    yLocation = startY
    while yLocation <= (height - 2 * spaceY):   # draw rectangles on rows 1, 3, 5, 7
        global xLocation
        xLocation = startX
        while xLocation <= (width - 2 * spaceX):
            drawRectangle()
            xLocation += 2 * spaceX
        yLocation += 2 * spaceY

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(startX + spaceX, startY + spaceY)
    turtle.pendown()
    yLocation = startY + spaceY
    while yLocation <= (height - spaceY):       # draw rectangles on rows 2, 4, 6, 8
        xLocation = startX + spaceX
        while xLocation <= (width - spaceX):
            drawRectangle()
            xLocation += 2 * spaceX
        yLocation += 2 * spaceY
```

that variable doesn't exist in that function. don't use global. You used height in

```
def drawChessboard(startX, startY, width = 250, height = 250):
```

so you need to do the same thing here

```
def drawAllRectangles(startX, startY, width, height):
```

so when you call drawAllRectangles make sure you pass in those 4 variables.

Also, move all your imports to the top of the files. and look up what eval does (https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval). You don't need globals or eval anywhere in your program.

Comment: When I remove global, all the variables aren't defined for use and I get errors. What can I do for that?

Answer (score 0):

> When I remove global, all the variables aren't defined for use and I
>   get errors. What can I do for that?

I agree with @anon (+1) about both globals and `eval()` in your code.  Below is my rework of your code sans globals -- you should be able to break it back into two separate files as required.  You need to (re)read about what the `global` keyword does and where it's used.  I understand `eval()` is convenient in inputting a tuple but you should find another way.  I replaced you other `eval()` calls with `int()`:

```
import turtle

def drawRectangle(xLocation, yLocation, spaceX, spaceY):

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(xLocation, yLocation)
    turtle.pendown()

    turtle.begin_fill()

    for _ in range(2):
        turtle.forward(spaceX)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(spaceY)
        turtle.left(90)

    turtle.end_fill()

def drawAllRectangles(startX, startY, width, height):
    """ Draw all rectangles to make up chessboard """

    spaceX = width / 8
    spaceY = height / 8

    yLocation = startY

    while yLocation <= (height - 2 * spaceY):  # draw rectangles on rows 1, 3, 5, 7
        xLocation = startX
        while xLocation <= (width - 2 * spaceX):
            drawRectangle(xLocation, yLocation, spaceX, spaceY)
            xLocation += 2 * spaceX
        yLocation += 2 * spaceY

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(startX + spaceX, startY + spaceY)
    turtle.pendown()

    yLocation = startY + spaceY

    while yLocation <= (height - spaceY):  # draw rectangles on rows 2, 4, 6, 8
        xLocation = startX + spaceX
        while xLocation <= (width - spaceX):
            drawRectangle(xLocation, yLocation, spaceX, spaceY)
            xLocation += 2 * spaceX
        yLocation += 2 * spaceY

def drawChessboard(startX, startY, width=250, height=250):

    """ Draw outside border for chessboard """

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(startX, startY)
    turtle.pendown()

    for _ in range(2):
        turtle.forward(width)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(height)
        turtle.left(90)

    drawAllRectangles(startX, startY, width, height)

def main():

    startX, startY = eval(input("Enter the starting coordinates (x, y): "))
    width = input("Enter the width: ")
    height = input("Enter the height: ")

    turtle.speed('fastest')

    if width == "" and height == "":
        drawChessboard(startX, startY)
    elif height == "":
        drawChessboard(startX, startY, width=int(width))
    elif width == "":
        drawChessboard(startX, startY, height=int(height))
    else:
        drawChessboard(startX, startY, int(width), int(height))

    turtle.done()

main()
```

It doesn't take this much code and effort to draw a chessboard with Python turtle.  I recommend you look into `stamp()` to both speed this up and simplify it.